# How to make 'emacs' indent with tabs exactly how 'nano' does...?

Tags: configuration, emacs, nano, indentation, tabs

How can I configure `~/.emacs` so that I indent how **nano** does by default?

- Uses a **tab** character instead of 5 spaces
- I can add as many tabs to a line as I please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following to `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq backward-delete-char-untabify-method nil)
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)

(defun my-insert-tab-char ()
"Insert a tab char. (ASCII 9, \t)"
(interactive)
(insert "\t"))
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'my-insert-tab-char) ; same as Ctrl+i
```